# git push to remote not accepting

Tags: git, git-push

My remote is configured not to accept non-fast-foward commits.

The remote version is completely different from my local version. I want to override it. I dont want to merge or rebase anything. Moreover, my local repository started as a clean git init, not pulling from the server.

I did `git push origin master --f` but I get

```
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
```

I dont want to pull because it will merge with my version and I dont want.

What's the right procedure to follow?

Comment: Might `--f` be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s either `git push -f origin master` or `git push --force origin master` but `git push --f` won’t work.

Comment: It's worth reiterating that this will *destroy all history* of any branches you forcibly override. Those changes will be gone forever.

Comment: Actually, git only **overrides the branch reference**. The objects itself are not immediately deleted and still exist in the objects database (`.git/objects`). However, a git garbage collection would finally destroy those dangling objects after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working in the same repo as you are going to push from, you need to pull first.

You can try to stash your changes :

```
git stash
```

When i started with git i had this error a lot of times. My solution was to work in a different directory then i pull from, making sure it never conflicts